# Can't decode exception in GAE hosted JSP page with JSTL localization

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, jstl

Could you please help me decode exception in GAE hosted JSP page with JSTL localization?

It works on dev server but fails in production so I can't really debug it. I tried googling for it too.

Exception doesn't give me meaningful information :(

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.LocalizationContext
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1018)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

JSP page is very simple:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.inject.Injector" %>
<%@ page import="com.mine.courierApp.server.Ofy" %>
<%@ page import="com.mine.courierApp.server.model.Order" %>
<%@ page import="com.mine.courierApp.server.model.DatastoreObject" %>
<%@ page import="com.googlecode.objectify.Key" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<c:if test="${lang == null}">
    <fmt:setBundle basename="com.mine.courierApp.server.Strings" var="lang" scope="session"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${param.lang != null}">
    <fmt:setLocale value="${param.lang}"/>
    <fmt:setBundle basename="com.mine.courierApp.server.Strings" var="lang" scope="session"/>
</c:if>
<%
    String orderId = request.getParameter("id");

    Injector inj = (Injector) application.getAttribute(Injector.class.getName());
    Ofy ofy = inj.getInstance(Ofy.class);

    Key<DatastoreObject> key = Key.create(orderId);
    Order order = (Order) ofy.load(key);
    if (order != null)
        application.setAttribute("stateId", "OrderState." + order.getState().name());
%>
<fmt:message key="StateOfOrderMsg" bundle="${lang}"/>
<b><fmt:message key="${stateId}" bundle="${lang}"/></b>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was glitch on my side. It doesn't happen with the latest build of SDK.